# Bootstrap form-check-inline not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/ form-check-inline without success, it renders the html by putting one checkbox under the other:

[image]

This is my html code:

```
<h1>Crear Paciente</h1>
<hr />

<form>
    <!-- #region General Data -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nombres y Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namesAndSurnames" placeholder="Nombres y Apellidos">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="birthDate">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>CI</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ci" placeholder="Cédula de Identidad">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Dirección</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Dirección">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Teléfono</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Teléfono">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Sociedad Médica</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="medicSociety" placeholder="Sociedad Médica">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Emergencia Móvil</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobileEmergency" placeholder="Emergencia Móvil">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Ocupación</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="occupation" placeholder="Ocupación">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Observaciones</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="observations" placeholder="Observaciones">
    </div>
    <!--#endregion -->
    <!-- #region Sicknesses -->
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="diabetes" value="diabetes">
        <label class="form-check-label">Diabetes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="heartProblems" value="heartProblems">
        <label class="form-check-label">Problemas Cardíacos</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="hypertension" value="hypertension">
        <label class="form-check-label">Hipertensión</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="metallicProsthesis" value="metallicProsthesis">
        <label class="form-check-label">Prótesis Metálicas</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="pacemaker" value="pacemaker">
        <label class="form-check-label">Marcapasos</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="pregnancies" value="pregnancies">
        <label class="form-check-label">Embarazos</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="surgeries" value="surgeries">
        <label class="form-check-label">Cirugías</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="allergies" value="allergies">
        <label class="form-check-label">Alergias</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Descripción de Alergias</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="allergiesDescription" placeholder="Describir las Alergias del Paciente">
    </div>
    <!--#endregion -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

I am also using electron though I doubt it has sth to do with this (it shouldn't).
All the former html code is being rendered with [w3-include-html](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) although it shouldn't affect either... this is the body html:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="includerDiv" w3-include-html="mainWindow.html"></div>
        <script>w3.includeHTML();</script>

        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>
                &copy;
                <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> - Beaspa - Versión 1.0
            </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's probably an issue with the w3-include-html. Your Bootstrap markup is fine: https://www.codeply.com/go/rdqYqLOEKs

Comment: Try to inspect the output html in the browser..

Comment: Can you try without 'w3-include-html'? I reviewed your code no clue found at all.

Comment: tried on chrome and it rendered the same page. I also copied and pasted the form in my main html to remove the w3-include-html, but it also rendered the same thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace `form-check form-check-inline` with `checkbox-inline` and it will work like an inline:

```
 <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="diabetes" value="diabetes">
            <label class="form-check-label">Diabetes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="heartProblems" value="heartProblems">
            <label class="form-check-label">Problemas Cardíacos</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="hypertension" value="hypertension">
            <label class="form-check-label">Hipertensión</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="metallicProsthesis" value="metallicProsthesis">
            <label class="form-check-label">Prótesis Metálicas</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="pacemaker" value="pacemaker">
            <label class="form-check-label">Marcapasos</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="pregnancies" value="pregnancies">
            <label class="form-check-label">Embarazos</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="surgeries" value="surgeries">
            <label class="form-check-label">Cirugías</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="allergies" value="allergies">
            <label class="form-check-label">Alergias</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: checkbox-inline class should be on the label tag